# How do i deal with extremely large json stdout in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, task

So I am using shell.js to execute unix commands in node.js, and I am using bull to queue the tasks. What basically happens is that i can give an array of tasks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        { 
            "name": "task1", 
            "command": "curl -XPOST --header \"Authorization: **********\" --header \"Accept: application/json\" --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" \"https://misp.****//attributes/restSearch/json/5.9.178.143/ip-dst\"" 
        },
        { 
            "name": "task2", 
            "command": "cat <input>" 
        }
    ]
}
```

and the output of first task gets saved into a file then can be used as the input of the second one. I was first trying to this using just memory but since the file is too large, so I thought saving it to a file could be a better option. But still stdout is saved in the memory I guess, so the bull worker fails at task 1. I need help dealing with this situation. If you could suggest a better architecture as well that would be really nice.

Here is my code so far:

worker.ts

```
import { exec } from "child_process";
import myQueue from "./queue";
import shell from 'shelljs';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

myQueue.process(async (job) => {
    console.log(`Processing job with id ${job.id}`);
    const tasks = job.data.tasks;
    let prevOutputFile = '';

    for (const [index, task] of tasks.entries()) {
        let command = task.command;

        // If <input> placeholder exists in command, replace it with previous output filename
        if (command.includes('<input>')) {
            if (prevOutputFile) {
                command = command.replace('<input>', prevOutputFile);
            } else {
                console.error('No previous output file available to serve as input');
                break;
            }
        }

        try {
            // Do not create a file if it's the last task
            if(index < tasks.length - 1) {
                const outputFile = path.join(__dirname, `${task.name}_output.txt`);
                const output = await execAsync(command, outputFile);

                console.log(`Task ${task.name} complete with output: ${output}`);
                prevOutputFile = outputFile;  // save the output filename for next task
            } else {
                const output = await execAsync(command);

                console.log(`Task ${task.name} complete with output: ${output}`);
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Task ${task.name} failed with error: ${error.message}`);
            break;
        }
    }
});

function execAsync(cmd: string, outputFile?: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
        shell.exec(cmd, {silent: true, async: true}, (code, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (code !== 0) {
                reject(new Error(stderr));
            } else {
                if(outputFile) {
                    fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, stdout);
                }
                resolve(stdout);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

server.ts

```
import express, { Request, Response } from 'express';
import myQueue from './queue';

const app = express();
app.use(express.json()); // add this line
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send('Hello, world!');
});

app.post('/taskChain', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const tasks = req.body.tasks;
    const newJob = await myQueue.add({
      tasks: tasks
    })

    res.json({id: newJob.id})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

queue.ts

```
import Bull from "bull";

const myQueue = new Bull('myQueue')

export default myQueue
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could provide some insight on how to design your code if dealing with sequential and task based operations like this. Thank you.

Comment: Read json by chunks with `@streamparser/json`: [Out-of-memory issue when using JSONStream in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76473093/out-of-memory-issue-when-using-jsonstream-in-nodejs). If you find this useful don't forget to upvote, thanks

Comment: yepp it worker. I used @streamparser/json but found something better. Thanks for the input, it helped a lot. Please check my answer below to see my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As per the thread that @Alexander Nenashev pointed me to, I tried several things. First, I attempted to use Steam, but the chunk was too large to be processed in memory. Then, I tried processing it character by character using @streamparser/json, and while it partially worked, I still needed a proper JSON output. After some searching, I discovered that this could be achieved with the 'stream-json' package using 'Parser', which tokenizes the content, and 'streamObject', which converts it back into a JSON object.

Here is my code:

```
import myQueue from "./queue";
import fs, { write }  from "fs";
import path from "path";
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import Parser from "stream-json/Parser";
import { streamObject } from 'stream-json/streamers/StreamObject'


myQueue.process(async(job) => {
    console.log(`Processing the job with id ${job.id}`);
    const tasks = job.data.tasks;
    let prevOutputFile  = '';
    let nextTaskFileDump = false

    for (const[index, task] of tasks.entries()) {
        let command = task.command;

        if (command.includes('<input>')) {
            if (prevOutputFile) {
                command = command.replace('<input>', prevOutputFile)
            } else {
                console.error('No previous output file available to serve as input');
                break; 
            }
        }

        if (tasks[index+1] && tasks[index+1].name == 'fileDump') {
            nextTaskFileDump = true;
        } else {
            nextTaskFileDump = false;
        }

        try {
            const outputFile = path.join(__dirname, `${task.name}_output_${index}.json`)
            if (task.name === 'fetchMispData' && nextTaskFileDump) {

            }
        }catch(error) {

        }
    }
} )

async function fetchAndWriteToFile(cmd:string, outputFile:string): Promise<void> {
    const [, authorization, mispLink, ip] = cmd.split(' ')
    
    const response = await fetch(`${mispLink}/${ip}/ip-dst`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': authorization,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })

    if(!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`)
    }

    const pipeline = response.body.pipe(new Parser().pipe(streamObject()))

    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputFile)

    pipeline.on('data', data=> {
        writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(data.valye, null, 2)  + ',\n');
    })

    pipeline.on('end', () => {
        writeStream.end();
    })

    pipeline.on('error', error => {
        console.error(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`)
    })
}
```