# What is the best and fastest method for the following problem? (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I have a json file with one million records, each record must be called as Body of an external api service and the json output result of that service is stored into the database.

(Preferably with nodejs)

I implemented with nodeJs and I read the json file and store it in an array and call that array to the service input one by one using the for loop (api call parallel) and push the result of the service into an array. Then insert array into the database.

```
 async function readJsonFile() {
  try {
    const jsonString = fs.readFileSync("./datas.json", "utf-8");
    const result = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}



    async function parallelApiCalls() {
  const apiCallPromises = [];
  // Fetch the token
  const token = await fetchToken();

  const IDs = await readJsonFile();

  const extractedData = IDs.map((item) => {
    return {
      identifier: {
        issuer: item.issuer,
        assigner: item.assigner,
        id: item.id,
        type: item.type,
      },
    };
  });

  async function pushArray(apiCallPromise) {
    apiCallPromises.push(apiCallPromise);
  }

  //Iterate over the custom bodies and cre of customBodieomises
  for (const item of extractedData) {
    const apiCallPromise = await siamOrganization(token, item);
    if (apiCallPromise.status.statusCode === 200 && apiCallPromise.data.data) {
      await pushArray(apiCallPromise.data.data);
    }
  }

  // Wait for all API call promises to resolve
  const apiCallResult = await Promise.all(apiCallPromises);

  await connectToSqlServer();
  await createTableIfNotExists();

  for (const result of apiCallResult) {
    // Process each API call result here
    try {
      await insertDataIntoTable([result]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Operation Failed Because: ", error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Read json by chunks with @streamparser/json:  [Out-of-memory issue when using JSONStream in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76473093/out-of-memory-issue-when-using-jsonstream-in-nodejs). If you find this useful don't forget to upvote, thanks

Comment: @Anuga The main goal is to provide a solution for better performance and less time in code execution

Comment: The problem is that : I have no problem reading and parsing the json file and this operation، I don't want to wait for the response from the service call, I want to create a queue as a batch file and immediately store the received response in the array. @AlexanderNenashev

Comment: @GhasemRoshan you could use web sockets to send packets?

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev ,  No i cannt use web sockets in app.