# JavaScript read of stream/chunks - force single chunk per read()

Tags: javascript, networking, streaming

TL;DR is there anyway to get the canonical JavaScript `read()` of a stream response to return only one chunk at a time?

The common implementations of reading a chunked stream (e.g., at MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader) all seem to have the "feature" that multiple (although no partial) chunks can be returned from one `read()`.  I'd be guessing at what the explanation is here, but it seems that the more time between reads, the more chunks are sent on each `read()`, so we can guess what is going on.

This is annoying when each chunk is valid JSON but multiple chunks aren't.

For example, I can see network traffic that looks like this (i.e., my API is generating well-defined chunks)

```
0b <- hex value of chunk length
{"value":1}
0c
{"value":10}
0e
{"value":null}
```

But a `read()` might return the string

```
{"value":1}{"value":10}{"value":null}
```

Thanks,
James

(UPDATE:  FWIW to posterity, the read will sometimes return partial chunk content.  You may only run into this in production on your blazing fast servers.  Using a delimiter, and either breaking apart chunks, or accumulating them, seems to solve both problems)

Comment: if you `return` after one chunk, how will you keep reading more chunks? perhaps I misinterpret what you mean by `return` though. Each `.read` seems to read one chunk in that example ...

Comment: @JaromandaX, i mean that the call to read() will return more than one chunk at a time.  I'll update the description

Comment: that is pretty much the canonical read() implemenation.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it is misleading. You can even find language in some of the MDN docs that makes it sound like read() only returns a single chunk.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: No, those lengths are part of the HTTP protocol, but they are generally not included in the response that is given to the calling code.  So, a non-chunked HTTP response will have a length in the header and that is how the HTTP layer in the stack knows how much to read from the TCP stream before it delivers the response to the requestor/caller.  For chunks, each chunk is delineated by the length for the same purpose.

Comment: OK, so based on the fact that `}{` is never valid in JSON (unless there's a value or even key with `}{` in it of course) and since I have no idea what type of data you're likely to be sending, a slightly naive approach could be [this](https://pastebin.com/NhPCk6vH) - personally, I'd be sending the chunks with a `\n` terminator or a length prefix of some kind, that way there's no mystery as to where each chunk is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Out-of-memory issue when using JSONStream in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76473093/out-of-memory-issue-when-using-jsonstream-in-nodejs)

Comment: There's no JS intrinsic way to do that. Use some library like `JSONStream`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no JS intrinsic way to do that. Use some library like `JSONStream`. A more elaborated approach could be found here: [Out-of-memory issue when using JSONStream in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76473093/out-of-memory-issue-when-using-jsonstream-in-nodejs)

Comment: I appreciate this (particularly the "no way to do that" which is what I've come to believe), but b/c the read() is turning valid JSON chunks into invalid JSON, i don't see how the JSONStream is going to help.